# how can I manage to display the table Product Display Node at the frontpage of my website instead of the default product display

Tags: drupal, product, commerce

I have seen and managed to do my products to be displayed like this http://vimeo.com/22746978 so I made the table of my products but how can I manage to display this table at the frontpage of my website so as when customer types example.com will see the table and not the default product display?
A hint is  when you make this Product display node, drupal makes you a url that you can see it but when I put as url the example.com it says that it cant be done so i need somehow to redirect the example.com to example.com/product-dispay-node so as to show it,but i do not know how.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your front page to point to any of your pages at **Configuration** >> **Site Information** >> under **Default front page** (at `admin/config/system/site-information`)

Comment: That was easy after all...!Thank you!